# Outlook | How to combine/group emails as in gmail?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, gmail, email-filter

Gmail combines/groups Emails with the same subject to one massage.
How can i have this kind of combining/grouping in MS Outlook?

**Long Version by example**

Initial Message

```
Paul -> Kate, Anna  
Subject: Thanks for the great party
```

Answers:

```
Kate -> Paul, cc: Anna  
Subject: Re: Thanks for the great party

Anna -> Paul, cc: Kate  
Subject: Re: Thanks for the great party
```

Now Paul goes back to his Emails:

- Gmail: 1 new message (including both responses)
- Outlook: 2 new messages

How can i archieve the Gmail-way in Outlook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, that is the way I have my Inbox setup. You need to use the `Conversation` settings.

Go to the view tab, choose the arrangement (mine is by date) and then checked `Show Conversations`. This groups all the messages with the same subject.

[image]